# SQL Server union all does not display all needed results

Tags: sql, sql-server, union-all

I need to display all result of this query (change + servicerequest + servizio)

```
select data, cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) as change
              from mainGrid
              where username = 'marco_polo' and
              YEAR(data) = 2020 and
              MONTH(data) = 5 and
              eventType = 'Change' 
              union all
select data, cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) as servicerequest
              from mainGrid
              where username = 'marco_polo' and
              YEAR(data) = 2020 and
              MONTH(data) = 5 and
              eventType = 'Service request'
              union all
select data, cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) as servizio
              from mainGrid
              where username = 'marco_polo' and
              YEAR(data) = 2020 and
              MONTH(data) = 5 and
              eventType = 'Servizio'
order by data
```

Running query I get only "change" values:

```
   data       change
---------------------
2020-05-30     9.15
2020-05-12     8.13
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `servicerequest` and `servizio` *are* being displayed, but they are in the column `change` as that's the alias you gave it in the first dataset. Perhaps you're misunderstanding what [`UNION (ALL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does. What are you're expected results here?

Comment: When you perform a `UNION` each part is a "combinable query". The first combinable query defines the names of the column. You don't need to specify aliases on the second or third query.

Comment: do you want 3 types in one column or 3 column at result?

Answer (score 0):

That would be because the other types are filtered out -- you probably have the names wrong.

In any case, you can write this more simply using `in`:

```
select m.event_type, m.data,
       cast((((m.ore*60.0)+m.minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) as change
from mainGrid m
where username = 'marco_polo' and and
      data >= '2020-05-01' and
      data < '2020-06-01' and
      eventType in ('Change' , ''Service request', 'Servizio');
```

This won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 3 types in separated column you can write:

```
 select data, 
  case when eventType = 'Change'  then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else 0 end as change,
  case when eventType = 'Service request' then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else 0 end as servicerequest, 
  case when eventType = 'Servizio' then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else  0 end as servizio
from mainGrid
where username = 'marco_polo' and
   YEAR(data) = 2020 and
   MONTH(data) = 5 and
   (eventType = 'Change' or eventType = 'Service request' or eventType = 
    'Servizio')
order by data
```

if you want 3 types in one column you can write:

```
 select data, cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) as calcColumn
from mainGrid
where username = 'marco_polo' and
   YEAR(data) = 2020 and
   MONTH(data) = 5 and
   (eventType = 'Change' or eventType = 'Service request' or eventType = 
    'Servizio')
order by data
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I get this:

```
   data          change            servicerequest    servizio
2020-05-30        0.00                  0.00          9.15
2020-05-12        0.00                  0.00          8.13
2020-05-30        0.00                 10.02          0.00
```

But I want to group by "data": in this case, for example,I want to see only one row with data = 2020-05-30. The problem is that if I simply add "group by data" I get an error that tells me that the others column are not used in the group by clause. So i added the other three columns (eventType, ore, minuti) in the group by clause like this:

```
select data, 
  case when eventType = 'Change' then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else 0 end as change,
  case when eventType = 'Service request' then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else 0 end as servicerequest, 
  case when eventType = 'Servizio' then cast((((ore*60.0)+minuti)/60) as decimal(10,2)) else  0 end as servizio
from mainGrid
where username = 'marco_polo' and
   YEAR(data) = 2020 and
   MONTH(data) = 5 and
   (eventType = 'Change' or eventType = 'Service request' or eventType = 'Servizio')
group by data, eventType, ore, minuti
order by data
```

But I get the same result and no grouping.

I need also to add a "total" column that gives me the total of the three types for every date. At the end I want to get something like this:

```
   data          change            servicerequest    servizio      total
2020-05-30        0.00                  10.02         9.15         10.15
2020-05-12        0.00                   0.00         8.13          8.13
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: @somaye javidmoradi can you help me please?